# Notifications pushed to LG G Watch appear after some delay

Tags: android, notifications, delay, watch, lg

I have been able to show notifications on LG G Android Wear Watch using below pointer.

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

However, there is a delay while the notifications are being popped up on the watch. But the notifications appear very quickly when I send notifications from Android Wear App's Demo Cards options from Handheld device. Any idea on the delay ?

Comment: are you using WearableExtender.setBackground(Bitmap) or NotificationCompat.Builder.setLargeIcon(Bitmap)?

Comment: Hi pskink...yes I am using exactly what u said..is that causing it???